# How to pass table column to rand function using spark.sql?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have one table with two columns `A` and `B` in hive metadata. I have to generate same random number when value of `A` and `B` pair is identical to other records.

Example: value pair `2.0 & 3.0` or `1.0 & 5.0` on those records using HASH function I will get `hash_code`. This `hash_code` I will pass to random function to get specific value for each matched records. I can simply pass `seed=123` to rand function but I am not able to pass table column to `rand` function.

[image]

###### Edit 1:

Function `rand(123)` with same seed will produce `identical results`.

[image]

Passing hash to rand:

```
spark.sql("select *,rand(hash(A,B)) from table1").show()
```

Getting below error:

```
AnalysisException: Input argument to rand must be an integer, long, or null constant.
```

How to pass `hash_code` to `rand` function using `spark.sql`?

Comment: Which version of spark are you using?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma spark 3.0

Comment: Even if it was possible to pass a column to `rand` function, the expression `rand(hash(A,B))` won't give the same result for the same inputs `A` and `B`. It's a non-deterministic function.

Comment: The `rand` function accepts a single `Long` as seed and not a column.

Comment: Looking at Spark code, in 3.2.0 `rand()` input parameters are strictly literals, so no iterable inputs from columns.  In your version, the error you got seems ambiguous but it also seems to behave the same way. I wouldn't use `rand(seed)` to generate deterministic values as the implementation is (still) not able to honor the usual deterministic behavior of seeded random number generation functions without some low-level kung-fu (i.e: fixing the partition count to 1).

Comment: @blackbishop - hash(A,B) is producing the same output, you can see in above screenshot. If I can pass same seed=123456 for particular record, then it will generate same random results.

Answer (score 1):

As also pointed out by some comments, `rand` [accepts only one parameter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#rand), the seed, which should be a constant, not an column (which is what you obtain from `hash(A, B)`).

If your purpose is producing a key from the columns `A` and `B`, then you shouldn't call any randomizing function. Just use the value of the hash.

Comment: my purpose is it produce random numbers based on hash code. If you look carefully hash_code is long or big-int number. I want the values between [0,1)

Answer (score 1):

Following on my comments, what you're looking for is simply not possible (at least for now) using Spark, for 2 mainly reasons:

- Function [`rand`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.rand.html) can take only constant parameters
- Also, it's a non-deterministic function, so calling `rand(hash(A,B))` in your dataframe won't give same result for same inputs `A` and `B`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# the function rand is called with same value 123, still give different results
spark.range(3).withColumn("rand", F.rand(123)).show()

#+---+-------------------+
#| id|               rand|
#+---+-------------------+
#|  0|0.24244888714603952|
#|  1| 0.4745014193615499|
#|  2|0.03951602781768582|
#+---+-------------------+
```

That said, if your intent is to get a value between `[0, 1]` from the hash result of `A` and `B`, then you could use this trick by dividing the hash by `10...0length_of_hash`:

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT  A, 
        B,  
        hash(A,B) / rpad('1', length(hash(A,B)) + 1, '0') AS Id  
FROM    table1
""").show()

#+---+---+------------+
#|  A|  B|          Id|
#+---+---+------------+
#|2.0|3.0|0.1475353518|
#|1.0|5.0| 0.649463331|
#|2.0|3.0|0.1475353518|
#|1.0|5.0| 0.649463331|
#+---+---+------------+
```